# Is it possible to have different types of output in shiny R?

Tags: r, shiny, multipleoutputs

I've been thinking if there's an answer to the question.

So i have this code in server.R

```
desc <- reactive({

  for (i in 1:input$txt1){
    print(paste("Cluster ke", i))
    clust <- ensemble()

    newdata <- clust[which(clust$Cluster==i), 1]
    print(paste(newdata))

    barm <- vector("numeric")
    x <- ncol(clust)-2

    for (j in 2:x){
      datdesc <- clust[which(clust$Cluster==i), j]
      m <- mean(datdesc)
      colnam <- colnames(clust[j])
      print(paste("Rata-rata produktivitas", colnam,":", m))

      for(k in j-1){
        barm[k] <- m
      }
    }
    print(paste(barm))
    barplot(barm)
  }
})

output$desc <- renderPrint({
    desc()
})
```

And this in the ui

```
conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==3", verbatimTextOutput("desc"))
```

So far, i can get all the output i wanted, the descriptive text and the bar plot. But, the bar plot is appears at the R console instead on the browser.

Is there any way to make the text and barplot show up at the same page?

Can i use other function of *renderPrint* or *verbatimTextOutput* that possibly can do that?

Or any other ways?

I've been thinking some solution to this, like dividing the *desc()* so it has two outputs, text and barplot. But if there's a way to make it in one go, I'm very much want to learn that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's common to have many different output types. Please see the Shiny gallery for more examples.

Based on the code you provided and a template:

**UI.R**

```
bootstrapPage(

  selectInput(
    "choice", "txt1 - descriptive text?",
    c(my_text = "my_text",
      your_text = "your_text")),

  selectInput(inputId = "n_breaks",
              label = "Number of bins in histogram (approximate):",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50),
              selected = 20),

  checkboxInput(inputId = "individual_obs",
                label = strong("Show individual observations"),
                value = FALSE),

  checkboxInput(inputId = "density",
                label = strong("Show density estimate"),
                value = FALSE),

  plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "300px"),

  conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice=='my_text'", verbatimTextOutput("desc"))


)
```

**Server.R**

```
function(input, output) {
  desc <- reactive({
    "some text goes here, I guess!"

  })

  output$desc <- renderPrint({
    desc()
  })

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({

    hist(faithful$eruptions,
         probability = TRUE,
         breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
         xlab = "Pandjie Soerja",
         main = "Pandjie Soerja")

    if (input$individual_obs) {
      rug(faithful$eruptions)
    }

    if (input$density) {
      dens <- density(faithful$eruptions,
                      adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    }

  })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that once I got off from the train. So, I assume I can also set the order whatever I want, right? Like text > plot > text > plot etc... Because as you can see, I use looping to generate the output.

Comment: @psdm You're welcome and yes you can. Any order top-to-bottom and left-to-right. It's very very flexible you know - you can do anything a website can do. You should look at the many examples here https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/